# VBA or Vb Scripting: how to write to a file in Unicode using FileSystemObject

Tags: unicode, filesystemobject

How would you use FileSystemObject to write to a string to a file in Unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument of [`OpenAsTextStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) determines if you want unicode or ascii.